# Norway Schengen visa processing time

Tags: visas, norway

I submitted a Schengen visa application to Norway.  I went for the interview on 27 April, and I have bought tickets for 18 May.  When will I get the visa?  Should I change my ticket?

Comment: Where did you have your interview?  Processing times probably vary from one consulate or service provider's office to the next.  Also, I've rewritten your question using some assumptions about what you're asking.  If I've misunderstood, please edit the question accordingly or leave a comment.

Comment: This is really something you should ask the embassy or consulate about.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.